# How to thank someone

Tags: politeness

How to thank someone who have helped me to know something knowledgeable or shared his knowledge with me:

1. Thank you for taking your time to share your knowledge with me.
2. Thank you to have shared your knowledge with me.
3. Thank you so much for taking the time for sharing your knowledge with me.

Are they proper way to thank someone? Are there any other way to thank someone politely?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge with me. Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me.

Comment: 1) _...for taking **the** time..._ 2) _Thank you **for sharing**..._ 3) _...for taking the time **to share**..._  ( @yubrajsharma - You can thank us here at ELL by remembering to place a space after _every_ full stop (or period, if you prefer).

Answer (score 3):

There are many, many different ways to thank someone politely.

The ways that you have listed are all more or less correct (minus a few grammatical errors) and any native English speaker would appreciate the effort you put into thanking them.

Numbers 1 & 3 are pretty much perfect, but i wouldn't use number 2 as it sounds too broken.

if i were to say numbers 1 & 3 respectively, i would say them like this:

1) Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge with me.

3) Thank you so much for taking the time to share your knowledge with me.

Alternative ways of thanking someone:

1) Thank you so much for helping me.

2) I greatly appreciate the time you've taken to share your knowledge with me.